# How do I use this code in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

How do I use this code in php :

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -i $2 -i $3 -i $4 -i $5 -i $6 -t 900 -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=$OUPUTSIZE [bg]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=$VIDEOSIZE [ul]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=$VIDEOSIZE [um]; [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=$VIDEOSIZE [ur]; [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=$VIDEOSIZE [ll]; [4:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=$VIDEOSIZE [lm]; [5:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=$VIDEOSIZE [lr]; [bg][ul] overlay=0:H/12 [out0]; [out0][um] overlay=W/3:H/12 [out1]; [out1][ur] overlay=2*W/3:H/12 [out2]; [out2][ll] overlay=0:7*H/12 [out3]; [out3][lm] overlay=W/3:7*H/12 [out4]; [out4][lr] overlay=2*W/3:7*H/12 " -threads 0 -map 0 -an -sn -dn -c:v libx264 -b:v 5600k -bufsize 12000k -maxrate 5000k -profile:v main -preset ultrafast -force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)' -flags -global_header -f segment -segment_list 6700k.m3u8 -segment_time 10 -segment_format mpeg_ts -segment_list_type m3u8 6700k-%d.ts
```

And what I need

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)?

Comment: Yes, but it did not work

Comment: "It did not work"? So what happened? Did you get the wrong result? Did you get an error message? Did your computer catch fire? You don't seem to have made any effort whatsoever to solve this issue by yourself. Why should I bother?

Answer (score 0):

You are using both ' and " in your execution. Try replacing the " with ' and do this:

exec("yourffmpegstring");